# Hyperlink not surrounding figure

Tags: graphics, hyperref

The clickable area of the hyperlink does not surround the image.

```
\href{https://github.com/}{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{img/github.png}}
```

Produces:

[image]

Desired behavior:

[image]

I can achieve something similar by writing some text afterwards...

```
\href{https://github.com/}{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{img/github.png} github}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Looks like it's a problem with `xelatex`. Cannot reproduce on `pdflatex`. Version info:

```
XeTeX  3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux)
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux)

Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
Package: hyperref 2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
```

Comment: please (again), provide complete small document, which reproduce showed image. your code snippet, as you can see from my answer, works well with `xelatex`!

Comment: @Zarko I used your example to test. Running `xelatex experiment.tex` produces [this PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2i59bo5jfjkmjp/experiment.pdf?dl=1).

Comment: apparently your test is not equal to mine. try with example image, then see  if  your latex installation is up-to -date. as you can see, my result are as you like to have.

Comment: I tried using the image you posted, but same result. I've edited in some versioning info above.

Comment: recent `hypperef` is 2018/02/06 v6.86b. i use miktex, recent version with recent version of all packages.

Comment: Same issue, I solved the problem (just a workaround) using the same solution as OP, but as I don't want text aside it, I've inserted the invisible Unicode char U+FEFF (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978720/invisible-characters-ascii)). BTW I'm using XeLaTeX as well `(version XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`.

Answer (score 1):

please always provide complete small document, which demonstrate your problem!

you have error in `\includegraphics[height=12]{example-image-a}` (observe missing units for height of image). for this you should received warnings: *Illegal unit of measure ...* . correct code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{https://github.com/}{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{example-image-a}}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

tested with `pdflatex` as well with `xelatex`. results are the same.

Comment: Sorry that was just a reproduction mistake. I did indeed use `12pt`.

Comment: than you shouldn't have any problems to obtain shoved result. if not, than you have something in your document, what you not show us. on such way is not possible to help you.

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with `xelatex`. `pdflatex` works fine.

Comment: even worse. how should i know this? i haven't telepathic ability :-(. anyway, see edited answer. i test with xelatex too and it works.